# ASP.NET Core MVC get Property of Property of Model from Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have these classes

```
public Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // [...] some other properties
}

public CustomerDetails
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    // [...] some other properties
}
```

i have this controller action

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{customer.id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details([FromQuery]CustomerDetails model)
{
    // [...]
}
```

i also have tried `[Route("{model.customer.id}")]` and `[Route("{id}")]` and added `[FromQuery]` to `CustomerDetails.Customer`
but `model.customer.id` is always `0`.

the action should have the route /customers/{model.customer.id}. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you share the Url you are using to call the GET action?

Comment: it is working with /customers/details?customer.id=5 but i want it to be /customers/5

Answer (score 0):

for url

```
/customers/details/5
```

change your action routing to this:

```
[Route("~/customers/details/{customerId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int customerId)
{
    // [...]
}
```

if your want url

```
/customers/5
```

you need this route attribute

```
[Route("~/customers/{customerId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int customerId)
{
    // [...]
}
```

if you add CustomerId to your model

```
public CustomerDetails
{
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    // [...] some other properties
}
```

it will we be working too

```
[Route("~/customers/details/{customerId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(CustomerDetails model)
{
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: He wanted the route to be `/customers/5` not `/customers/details/5`

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

> i also have tried [Route("{model.customer.id}")] and [Route("{id}")]
> and added [FromQuery] to CustomerDetails.Customer but
> model.customer.id is always 0.
>
> the action should have the route /customers/{model.customer.id}. How
> can I achieve this?
>
> it is working with /customers/details?customer.id=5 but i want it to
> be /customers/5

According to your code and description, I suppose perhaps you want to get the parameter from route, instead of the query.

Try to modify your code as below:

1. Use `[FromRoute]` attribute.
2. From your description, it seems that you just want to pass the customer id to the action method, so there is no need to use the CustomerDetails  as parameter.

   ```
    [HttpGet] 
    [Route("Test/Details/{customerid}")]
    public IActionResult Details([FromRoute]int customerid)
    {
        // [...]
        ViewBag.CustomerId = customerid;
        return View();
    }
   ```

Code in the View Page:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

@ViewBag.CustomerId
```

The result like this:

[image]